# Error while executing get request firebase, error: 'Unauthorized request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, service

[my rules are as bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMhCC.png)

[database in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2qha.png)

[this is where im calling api url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa5Gi.png)

[image]
i am trying to fetch data from firebase api in angular but facing 'Unauthorized request error, i tried for post req as well, tried in another service and component as well but it still the same.
i simply added one json file to firebase and trying to fetch in my project.

Comment: Please dont provide screenshots of ANY code or errors. Instead copy and paste them here.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your Firebase console, and copy your project Firebase Config. Then pass it to the initializeApp method.
For example, this implementation shows Google Auth:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        const auth = getAuth(app);
        useDeviceLanguage(auth);

        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

        const R = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

**To find your Firebase Config, go to this [link](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/), then select your project. Now go to the bottom  (your apps section), select the config option from the SDK setup and configuration menu, and copy it.**